# Why is my break statement not performing as I would expect it to?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
def main():
    stringsList = []    # empty list to hold inputted strings
    getInput(stringsList)

def getInput(stringsList):
    minWords = 0
    while minWords < 8:
        stringInput = str(input('Enter a word, x to exit: ')) 
        stringsList.append(stringInput)
        minWords = minWords + 1

        if stringInput == 'x': 
            break
    print('Exiting application')


# ask user to select modified list
    userChoice = input(
        '''
        Sort Ascending:     1
        Sort Descending:    2 
        (Choose an option)  
        '''
    )
    if userChoice == '1':
        SortByIncreasingLength(stringsList)
    elif userChoice == '2':
```

My intent is that if the user enters "x", then the loop terminates and should print "Exiting application".

Instead, it continues on to the userChoice variable which will be a menu system. Here's a sample output:

```
Enter a word, x to exit: x
Exiting application

        Sort Ascending:     1
        Sort Descending:    2
        (Choose an option)
```

What am I missing? I can't seem to put a finger on why this shouldn't work as I expect it to.

Comment: It looks like your question was answered. If so, please accept the answer so that the rest of us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `break` statement will exit the loop (and go to the next line in the function that is outside the loop), but it will not exit the program. If you want to exit the program when the user enters 'x', you want to call `return` (this will exit the function) or `exit()` (to exit python) instead

Here's the fixed code:

```
def getInput(stringsList):
    minWords = 0
    while minWords < 8:
        stringInput = str(input('Enter a word, x to exit: ')) 
        stringsList.append(stringInput)
        minWords = minWords + 1

        if stringInput == 'x': 
            print('Exiting application')
            exit()
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue and gave me the desired output: 

`if stringInput == 'x': 
            print('Exiting application')`

Comment: `print('Exiting application')` should be moved to right before `exit()`, no?

Comment: @digilink please see this link on how to accept answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You must put all your code inside the while loop to exit when break is called.